# App Crashes on iPhone but not in Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I am fairly new to iOS development, and currently an app I am creating for a real estate company crashes when I switch storyboards on an actual iPhone, but works flawlessly in the simulator. I've triple-checked my code, and everything seems fine. Here is the website I got the code from: http://www.skillmasters.net/main/xcode-using-multiple-storyboards/.

And here is the crash report:

```
Incident Identifier: E6C2C623-BBAC-4F4B-8C90-C08F1F61EADF
CrashReporter Key:   e86ddaf63451cf9a7b4ed5e011de01e23b0ebec0
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:         Island House Sellers [6338]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/3C9E194F-8A24-4E62-A82D-8A53D73D337D/Island House Sellers.app/Island House Sellers
Identifier:      Island House Sellers
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-05-17 13:55:32.120 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3557988f 0x354c0000 + 759951
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37920259 0x37917000 + 37465
2   UIKit                           0x333255fb 0x32faa000 + 3651067
3   Island House Sellers            0x000ebcb3 -[ViewController gotostoryboard3] (ViewController.m:27)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x354d33fd 0x354c0000 + 78845
5   UIKit                           0x32fc8e07 0x32faa000 + 126471
6   UIKit                           0x32fc8dc3 0x32faa000 + 126403
7   UIKit                           0x32fc8da1 0x32faa000 + 126369
8   UIKit                           0x32fc8b11 0x32faa000 + 125713
9   UIKit                           0x32fc9449 0x32faa000 + 128073
10  UIKit                           0x32fc792b 0x32faa000 + 121131
11  UIKit                           0x32fc7319 0x32faa000 + 119577
12  UIKit                           0x32fad695 0x32faa000 + 13973
13  UIKit                           0x32facf3b 0x32faa000 + 12091
14  GraphicsServices                0x3716c22b 0x37167000 + 21035
15  CoreFoundation                  0x3554d523 0x354c0000 + 578851
16  CoreFoundation                  0x3554d4c5 0x354c0000 + 578757
17  CoreFoundation                  0x3554c313 0x354c0000 + 574227
18  CoreFoundation                  0x354cf4a5 0x354c0000 + 62629
19  CoreFoundation                  0x354cf36d 0x354c0000 + 62317
20  GraphicsServices                0x3716b439 0x37167000 + 17465
21  UIKit                           0x32fdbcd5 0x32faa000 + 203989
22  Island House Sellers            0x000ebb69 main (main.m:16)
23  Island House Sellers            0x000ebb14 0xea000 + 6932


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35e2f32c 0x35e1e000 + 70444
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3297b208 0x3292e000 + 315912
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32974298 0x3292e000 + 287384
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x35931f64 0x3592b000 + 28516
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3592f346 0x3592b000 + 17222
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37920350 0x37917000 + 37712
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3592f3be 0x3592b000 + 17342
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3592f44a 0x3592b000 + 17482
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3593081e 0x3592b000 + 22558
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x379202a2 0x37917000 + 37538
10  CoreFoundation                  0x354cf506 0x354c0000 + 62726
11  CoreFoundation                  0x354cf366 0x354c0000 + 62310
12  GraphicsServices                0x3716b432 0x37167000 + 17458
13  UIKit                           0x32fdbcce 0x32faa000 + 203982
14  Island House Sellers            0x000ebb62 main (main.m:16)
15  Island House Sellers            0x000ebb0c 0xea000 + 6924

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35e1f3a8 0x35e1e000 + 5032
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x34409f04 0x34406000 + 16132
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x34409c22 0x34406000 + 15394

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35e1f004 0x35e1e000 + 4100
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35e1f1fa 0x35e1e000 + 4602
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3554d3ec 0x354c0000 + 578540
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3554c124 0x354c0000 + 573732
4   CoreFoundation                  0x354cf49e 0x354c0000 + 62622
5   CoreFoundation                  0x354cf366 0x354c0000 + 62310
6   WebCore                         0x313cec9c 0x31325000 + 695452
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3293c72e 0x3292e000 + 59182
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3293c5e8 0x3292e000 + 58856

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35e2fcd4 0x35e1e000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32936f36 0x3292e000 + 36662
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32936cc8 0x3292e000 + 36040

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3eb86d98      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2fee8a40
    r8: 0x0d62fd90    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x3338c8cc     r11: 0x00000001
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fee8a34      lr: 0x3297b20f      pc: 0x35e2f32c
  cpsr: 0x00070010

Binary Images:
   0xea000 -    0xedfff +Island House Sellers armv7  <607a28905ab231a3b9c880aea83198a3> /var/mobile/Applications/3C9E194F-8A24-4E62-A82D-8A53D73D337D/Island House Sellers.app/Island House Sellers
 0x3ee4000 -  0x3ee7fff  QuickSpeak armv7  <06848e83ddc638dfaf1250093ea9ca39> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/QuickSpeak.bundle/QuickSpeak
0x2fee9000 - 0x2ff0afff  dyld armv7  <77eddfd654df393ba9c95ff01715fd08> /usr/lib/dyld
0x302c1000 - 0x302c7fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x3039b000 - 0x304c0fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x304fa000 - 0x30500fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x30583000 - 0x30598fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x306aa000 - 0x306adfff  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x306ae000 - 0x306f6fff  CoreMedia armv7  <e274e1b894753b2eb05cf7b22a36d0c1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x30732000 - 0x30c76fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x31325000 - 0x31ae4fff  WebCore armv7  <2690c38c9c5f3c09975d619dd1dfbed7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x31af7000 - 0x31bcffff  vImage armv7  <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x31bd0000 - 0x31db4fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x31db5000 - 0x31dfffff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x31e27000 - 0x31e3dfff  libmis.dylib armv7  <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x31e49000 - 0x32006fff  ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3217f000 - 0x32190fff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x323a3000 - 0x32494fff  QuartzCore armv7  <35d64a9da5523ae08c9e41511fd3061b> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x324a7000 - 0x324aafff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x32584000 - 0x325a4fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x32601000 - 0x3260dfff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x3260e000 - 0x32631fff  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x326e3000 - 0x3272dfff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f1fbb825def23043830a095b953a9c94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x32748000 - 0x3274efff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x32751000 - 0x32755fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x32756000 - 0x32757fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x32758000 - 0x32759fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <6a8f2f33c7543808a0f4599101c3b61a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x32768000 - 0x3276afff  MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x32905000 - 0x32929fff  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x3292e000 - 0x329bafff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x32a31000 - 0x32a42fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x32ac0000 - 0x32ac1fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x32ac2000 - 0x32ac5fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x32bad000 - 0x32be8fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x32faa000 - 0x3344cfff  UIKit armv7  <cd513a2f22f53d698c3e10f6fe48a63e> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x335a2000 - 0x335e7fff  GeoServices armv7  <a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x33626000 - 0x3362bfff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x33865000 - 0x338aefff  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x338b1000 - 0x338e4fff  Preferences armv7  <f1a9b0b7ffbe3c44877f5e7ba44d4a2f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Preferences.framework/Preferences
0x339f1000 - 0x339f7fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x33add000 - 0x33ae7fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x33e9d000 - 0x33eacfff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <a2363f8ed49932dba415d2d4cd32fb74> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x33ead000 - 0x33eb2fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x33eb9000 - 0x33ec3fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x33f9d000 - 0x33fc2fff  OpenCL armv7  <f4b08361179a3f6bb033415b0d7c6251> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x33ffe000 - 0x34014fff  EAP8021X armv7  <952fcfdec0633aff923768fca1a26fcb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x3406b000 - 0x340a9fff  IOKit armv7  <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x340aa000 - 0x340c0fff  VoiceServices armv7  <c5b98e94eff33bf49006ff157c819987> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VoiceServices.framework/VoiceServices
0x3421a000 - 0x34363fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x34364000 - 0x34364fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x34365000 - 0x34370fff  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x3438c000 - 0x343c3fff  Security armv7  <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x34401000 - 0x34405fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x34406000 - 0x3441cfff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x34444000 - 0x34495fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x34496000 - 0x3449dfff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <38132ecfd74b325fb1a4142bab663c19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x34568000 - 0x34569fff  CoreSurface armv7  <97f871f09f503c98a6371c2b657430d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3458b000 - 0x34597fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x34598000 - 0x345abfff  AssistantServices armv7  <4a0843742f363a8885b8db13b44ae256> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices
0x345c9000 - 0x345d1fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x345d2000 - 0x345d6fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x34761000 - 0x34775fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <54091a638f8731cd85ccf00fa06972c3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x34b46000 - 0x34b8afff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x34bbc000 - 0x34bc9fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x34d6c000 - 0x34e43fff  CFNetwork armv7  <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x34e44000 - 0x34ec3fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x34ff8000 - 0x35176fff  Foundation armv7  <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x35252000 - 0x35322fff  WebKit armv7  <3c5dd2ec46fe3e189c25bba78ad88fa1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x35459000 - 0x3545ffff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x35463000 - 0x354acfff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x354ad000 - 0x354b0fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x354b8000 - 0x354bcfff  libAXSpeechManager.dylib armv7  <a8cd1b0b9702334b90fba44d36577b40> /usr/lib/libAXSpeechManager.dylib
0x354c0000 - 0x355d7fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x35762000 - 0x357bafff  CoreAudio armv7  <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x357bd000 - 0x357bdfff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x357c6000 - 0x357d5fff  OpenGLES armv7  <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x357d6000 - 0x357d6fff  Accelerate armv7  <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x357d9000 - 0x357e8fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x3592b000 - 0x35932fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x35959000 - 0x359a5fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <b8f80d5d594c31d2b5d8fba9fdedb7e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x35a28000 - 0x35ad2fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x35af4000 - 0x35af7fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x35b14000 - 0x35b17fff  NetworkStatistics armv7  <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x35b1e000 - 0x35c63fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x35c64000 - 0x35c70fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x35c71000 - 0x35ca9fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x35caa000 - 0x35cc0fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x35e1e000 - 0x35e34fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <311f379a9fde305d80c1b22b7dd2e52a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x35e69000 - 0x35e71fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x35e7a000 - 0x35e7afff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <eb82984fa36c329387aa518aa5205f3d> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x3604f000 - 0x3604ffff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <a80aaa9989483ce3a496a061fd1e9e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x3605b000 - 0x36149fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x36199000 - 0x3619afff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x36212000 - 0x3622bfff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <1828cddc5dd93c61afbefb59587d7f8a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x36264000 - 0x36311fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3632a000 - 0x3636dfff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x3636e000 - 0x3636ffff  DataMigration armv7  <d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x363a6000 - 0x363aafff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x363c8000 - 0x363ccfff  IOSurface armv7  <443ac3aab9283da480dd9dcda3c5c88e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x36600000 - 0x36601fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x36645000 - 0x366befff  ProofReader armv7  <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x366bf000 - 0x366defff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x36748000 - 0x36784fff  AppSupport armv7  <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x36c23000 - 0x36c27fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d6a7436ed8dc33d795c9b42baf864882> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x36c28000 - 0x36c98fff  CoreImage armv7  <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x37167000 - 0x37171fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <cb64e146a8ee3fda9e80ffae1ccc9c5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x372c6000 - 0x37587fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x37635000 - 0x37637fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x37640000 - 0x37675fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x3770b000 - 0x3774bfff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x37917000 - 0x379ddfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x37a1a000 - 0x37a68fff  CoreLocation armv7  <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x37ab7000 - 0x37ab7fff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x37ab8000 - 0x37ad5fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x37b1a000 - 0x37b23fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x37b93000 - 0x37b93fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x37bb5000 - 0x37c06fff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
```

Here is the contents of the Viewcontroller.m:

```
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

-(void)contactreturn {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)gotostoryboard2 {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard2 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboard2" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *storyboard2VC = [storyboard2 instantiateInitialViewController];
    storyboard2VC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:storyboard2VC animated:YES];


}

-(void)gotostoryboard3 {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard3 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboard3" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *storyboard3VC = [storyboard3 instantiateInitialViewController];
    storyboard3VC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:storyboard3VC animated:YES];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

Again, this all works fine in the simulator...

Comment: Post the contents of `ViewController.m`.  It's unlikely anybody can help you debug the code without seeing it.

Comment: @Jim Ok, here it is. If you would like the contents of all the other Viewcontoller Subclasses, let me know.

Comment: Make sure you're including the Storyboard files in the Copy Bundle Resources section of Xcode. (Under Target > Build Phases).

Comment: check the targetted os of the device

Comment: Is that the full, unaltered source code from the build that generated the error?  The crash log is saying it crashed on line 27, but that's a blank line.

Comment: Maybe you wrote in code "storyboard2" and your file is named "Storyboard2", this crashes on device and not in simulator because simulator takes files caseinsentive.

Comment: Thank you @Retterdesdialogs I actually figured that out just before you posted. I never would've suspected that the simulator was case insensitve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you wrote in code "storyboard2" and your file is named "Storyboard2", this crashes on device and not in simulator because simulator takes files caseinsentive. – Retterdesdialogs

I never would've assumed the simulator wasn't case sensitive. Thanks Very Much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dropping in a bunch of break points and seeing what in the code is causing the crash?

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation similar to Cole Fletcher described above. In my case, I used a new storyboard, and forgot to put in the new story name/view controller storyboard ID in the code. It crashed on the device. Still don't know why it worked in the first place on simulator ??